# Unable to delete input field using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have a `HTML` input field, that is pre-filled with `email` value after the page is open. 
See pictures bellow. It appears as a text box that can be deleted with backspace and I can type in that field. But what is a proper way removing it with selenium? I tried `send_keys`, and `clear()` with different variables but so far it wouldn't locate it properly or delete. I can click in the text input where the `email` is but that's about it. In the source code it show `<li class>` located in `<span>` tags.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please share the html of the `<select>` tag under the `<span class="editmode">`

Comment: @supputuri `<option class=" " value="11006" title="Email">Email</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use the below option to clear the items that are already present.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='search-choice-close']").click()
```

if you want to close all the already selected items then use `find_elements` and iterate.

Comment: Thanks, that did it